# Is ko.mapping.fromJS method depreceated in knockout 2.2 and 3?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a problem to use   `ko.mapping.fromJS(`  in knockout. I've been testing on version 2.2 and 3. 
Anybody else who has had problems? Or are there any other alternatives to updating a instatieted viewmodel?

```
if (PAGE.blogViewModel == null) {
                    PAGE.blogViewModel = new BlogViewModel(data);
                    ko.applyBindings(PAGE.blogViewModel, document.getElementById("blog_container"));
                } else {
                    ko.fromJSON(data, PAGE.blogViewModel); 
                }
```

The updating `ko.fromJSON(data, PAGE.blogViewModel);` does not work.

```
*TypeError: ko.fromJSON is not a function*
```

And oddly enough I've used  `ko.mapping.fromJS(` before and it has worked.

> ko.mapping.fromJS(data, PAGE.blogViewModel);

*TypeError: ko.mapping is undefined*

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Can you include a repro of the problems you're having?

Comment: Please define "does not work."! What is not working?

Comment: ko.mapping is a plugin to knockout and not a part of knockout itself. Have you included the correct version of the mapping plugin in both tests?

Comment: No I haven't. Did not know that.

Comment: @marko It says so on [the documentation page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Maybe you should have looked there. ;)

Comment: Yeah I should have. RFML? You just need luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ko.mapping.fromJS` is not deprecated because it was never part of the core Knockout library.

The `ko.mapping.fromJS` is comming from the [Knockout Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

You need to [download](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output) and include it separately in your HTML to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't included the [ko.mappings-library](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). Make sure that it is loaded after Knockout is loaded.